# Prevent selection screen input fields conversion to upper case?

Tags: abap, dynpro

I have the table with field `title_medi` which contains two rows like **Mr.** and  **Ms.**

Also I have input field called title with search help of `title_medi`. When I'm selecting **Mr.** in the search help it gets displayed in the textfield.

If I compare that text field value with the database field. I'm getting an error.

But when I debug and see the value is somewhat getting converted to all uppercase like **MR.**  not as exactly in the table.

Could you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 6):

In order to solve this you have 2 options:

1. Go to the domain of the table field and check *Lower case* [check this](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi71/helpdata/en/cf/21edf2446011d189700000e8322d00/content.htm)
2. Use TRANSLATE ABCD TO LOWER CASE before making the comparison [check this](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw2004s/helpdata/en/fc/eb33a5358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm)

Answer (score 1):

additional info

In HR, possible quality (Mr, Ms...) are stored in table t522. Corresponding texts are stored in T522T. The data element is ANREX, associated with the domain of same name. This domain is lower case enabled.

moreover, this also give you the person's gender.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the data element but that is also been checked with the lower case. 
So what i did is i have checked the check-box for upper/lower case attribute in screen painter for the concern field. It works fine

Answer (score 0):

Use [`LOWER CASE`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abapparameters_value.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_2@2@) addition to PARAMETERS, if you refer to selection screen input field.

```
PARAMETERS: p_matnr LIKE mara-matnr LOWER CASE.
```

I don't know which version OP was using as this is really old question, but this addition is available at least since ABAP 700 SP05